# Change plot margins in R to obtain a "rectangular plot"

Tags: r, plot, margins

I am trying to generate graphs with the x-axis length bigger than y-axis height. I am using distribution with long right tails and in order to accomodate the entire representation, i need to augment the length of x. 
If i use:

```
plot(x , y, type="l", xlim=c(.. , ..))
```

it will only rescale the x axis, not lengthen it. In other words, i would like to generate a figure in a "rectangular" box plot while R generates quadratic boxes by default.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You could probably specify `par(pin = c(width, height))` before plotting. See `?par`

Comment: I tried with plot(... , par(width = .. , height=..)) but it displays an error saying that width and height are not graphical parameters. Maybe it's a matter of syntax

Comment: It works. Thanks. Sorry for the basic question but i am new to R

Answer (score 0):

Rstudio allows you resize the graphs with clicking with your mouse.

Simulating a sort of bell shaped Witch of Agness type curve:

```
> fx <- function(x){1 / (1 + x^2)}
> plot(fx, from = -10, to = 10)
```

In the plot window click "Export" > "Save as Image" 
It gives you a default width and height, and you can change that by writing new numbers in Width and Height boxes. I think these numbers are the number of pixels, so if you want the image, to be twice as wide as it is long, set the width to 800 and the height to height to 400. Then click "Update Preview".
Finally save the image when you get it right. I think setting the width to 800, and the height to 500 would look a little better.